# Tesseract : can't use command nochop makebox

Tags: python, ubuntu, ocr, tesseract

I installed tesseract on Ubuntu, because I wanted to train tesseract and import it to python script so that I can use it easily. I followed this step.

```
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool 
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf-archive 
$ sudo apt-get install pkg-config 
$ sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libleptonica-dev
```

I installed tessearct too, and run this command

```
which tesseract
```

and there was no result. So I decided to edit enviroment, so I opened file .pam_environment and added this line

```
TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/
```

and also I opened .bash_profile and added this line

```
TESSDATA_PREFIX=/urs/local/tesseract-ocr/
```

and tried to make box file by using this command

```
tesseract file.tif file batch nochop makebox
```

What I got was error message.

```
read_params_file: Can't open nochop
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v2cc531e with Leptonica
Page 1
```

and I still don't get the result when I run this command

```
which tessearct
```

I wonder how can I fix it

Comment: Exactly how did you install Tesseract? What operation have you done?

Comment: @check-emee I ran this command ./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-debug
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" make
sudo make install
sudo make install-langs
sudo ldconfig

Comment: @check-emee I uninstalled all things and reinstalled again. now when I run command 'which tesseract' it shows result but still cant run command 'nochop makebox'

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason of the error. First of all, there were two tesseract installed and one was not compiled correctly. Also, the commend should be changed like this.

```
tesseract file.tif file batch.nochop makebox
```